# in C# ASP.NET application how task done and who do that ? CLR or IIS express?

Tags: c#, asp.net, clr, iis-express

suppose i have a web application who send the mail then who really send the mail. i know the application have a code to send mail but who do that IIS web server [express] who i run with Visual studio or CLR who in the system of mine.

can someone show me process in this condition how mail goes. the application have code for sending mail but how they got exeute. IIS execute them or execute in CLR through IIS

IIS send the mail or CLR in my system do that. can someone show me logic flow

Answer (score 1):

All of the code is executed by your code in the ASP.NET worker process. Your code is compiled into one or more assemblies (DLL) which are loaded into the worker process and executed.

All that IIS does is direct requests to the worker process.

Visual Studio has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The agent actually sending the mail is the mail server you connect to. The IIS worker process basically instantiate a socket and via the SMTP protocol send the commands to the server to send the mail. This protocolo is pretty simple and consists of various string sent via a TCP channel to the SMTP server to instruct it to send the message to the recipient.